# Return value of Mock_Response::getBody() must be an instance of Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface, string returned in PHPUnit test with 9.5.10

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, guzzle

I have recently upgraded to PHPUnit 9.5.10 in my Symfony 4 application and now I seem to have a bunch of failed tests related to a HTTP call I am making to an endpoint with Guzzle.

The failure is:

```
1) Tests\AppBundle\Services\CourseTest::testUpdateAssignedCourseFromKey with data set "valid Course, current refkey" (AppBundle\Entity\Referral Object (...), array(true), AppBundle\Entity\Site Object (...), 'lambda')
TypeError: Return value of Mock_Response_0807f175::getBody() must be an instance of Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface, string returned

/private/var/www/crmpicco/src/AppBundle/Services/Course.php:250
/private/var/www/crmpicco/src/AppBundle/Services/Course.php:187
/private/var/www/crmpicco/src/AppBundle/Services/Course.php:92
/private/var/www/crmpicco/Tests/AppBundle/Services/CourseTest.php:99
```

My test method looks like this:

```
    /**
     * @dataProvider refkeyProvider
     *
     * @param Referral $referral
     * @param Site     $site
     * @param $expectedpartner
     *
     * @internal param Person $person
     */
    public function testUpdateAssignedCourseFromKey(Referral $referral, $apiresult, Site $site, $expectedCourse)
    {
        $apiresult = json_encode($apiresult);
        $response = $this->getMockBuilder('GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response')->getMock();
        $response->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getBody')
            ->will($this->returnValue($apiresult));
        $client = $this->getMockBuilder('\GuzzleHttp\Client')->getMock();
        $client->expects($this->any())
            ->method('request')
            ->will($this->returnValue($response));

        $partner = new Course($this->username, $this->password, $client);
        $partner->setDoctrine($this->getDoctrine());

        $owner = $site->getOwner();
        $partner->updateAssignedCourseFromKey($site, $referral);

        $this->assertEquals($owner->getRefkey()->getRefkey(), $referral->getRefkey());
        $this->assertEquals($site->getRefkey()->getRefkey(), $referral->getRefkey());

        if (self::ANY_COURSE == $expectedcourse) {
            $this->assertNotEmpty($site->getOwner()->getCourseShortname());
        } else {
            $this->assertEquals($site->getOwner()->getCourseShortname(), $expectedcourse);
        }
    }
```

Line 250 is `$data = json_decode($response->getBody());` which is the response of a HTTP call with Guzzle.

```
composer show | grep guzzle 
guzzlehttp/guzzle                    7.4.0              Guzzle is a PHP HTTP client library
guzzlehttp/promises                  1.5.1              Guzzle promises library
guzzlehttp/psr7                      2.1.0              PSR-7 message implementation that also provides common utility methods

composer show | grep phpunit
phpunit/php-code-coverage            9.2.7              Library that provides collection, processing, and rendering functionality for PHP code coverage i...
phpunit/php-file-iterator            3.0.5              FilterIterator implementation that filters files based on a list of suffixes.
phpunit/php-invoker                  3.1.1              Invoke callables with a timeout
phpunit/php-text-template            2.0.4              Simple template engine.
phpunit/php-timer                    5.0.3              Utility class for timing
phpunit/phpunit                      9.5.10             The PHP Unit Testing framework.
```

Comment: Super personal opinion, use Mockery, it is the best for mocking... This will not happen to you again

Comment: @matiaslauriti Thanks for the suggestion. Any recommendation on how to fix this test as a short-term stop gap? I have inherited this test from another developer, I did not write it.

Comment: I think you are using Symfony, so I am of no help then, because if you were using Laravel, you can simply use [`Http::fake()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#faking-specific-urls), sorry.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Yes, sorry, I have added that to the question. I should've made that clearer.

Answer (score 5):

There is my workaround.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream;

$responseMock->expects($this->once())->method('getBody')->willReturn(new Stream(fopen('data://text/plain,' . $yourString,'r')));
```

Comment: This fixed PHPUnit error. But PHPStan gives the below error: 
Parameter #1 $stream of class GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream constructor expects resource, resource|false given.

Comment: This is because `fopen` returns a file pointer resource on success, or false on error. You can add additional check `if ($resource = fopen(...)) {new Stream($resource)}`